# Check if mySql is installed on server

Tags: linux, mysql

Is there a way to determine if mySql has been installed on a Linux server?

Comment: If you need to downvote this question, please tell me why?

Comment: Probably because you didn't ask your question well.  Here's the de facto way to do it right:

 http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming that you are looking for a mysql binary installed with a typical package, run the command:

```
mysql
```

or

```
mysql --version
```

If it comes back with a response, it is installed, if it says "command not found" then it is not installed.

Comment: Assuming that it's in the path or current directory.

Comment: Also assuming it wasn't compiled to use a different name! :)

Answer (score 2):

What version of linux?

Debian
dpkg -l 'mysql*'

Answer (score 1):

How about `rpm -q mysql` (Fedora/RedHat)

Comment: rpm -qa | grep mysql is probably safer since the main package is mysql-server

Answer (score 1):

Other than the good suggestions above, try:

```
locate mysqld_safe
```

or

```
ls /etc/init.d | grep mysql
```

If you think it might be running already try:

```
ps waxu | grep mysql
```

or

```
netstat -pan | grep mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

On every distribution that I know of, MySQL installs some shared libraries for its client, named appropriately limbysqlclient. You can check for this by using the ldconfig tool, which will query to see if the object is installed:

```
ldconfig -p | grep mysqlclient
        libmysqlclient_r.so.15 (libc6) => /usr/lib/libmysqlclient_r.so.15
        libmysqlclient_r.so.14 (libc6) => /usr/lib/libmysqlclient_r.so.14
        libmysqlclient_r.so.12 (libc6) => /usr/lib/libmysqlclient_r.so.12
        libmysqlclient_r.so.10 (libc6) => /usr/lib/libmysqlclient_r.so.10
        libmysqlclient_r.so (libc6) => /usr/lib/libmysqlclient_r.so
        libmysqlclient.so.15 (libc6) => /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so.15
        libmysqlclient.so.14 (libc6) => /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so.14
        libmysqlclient.so.12 (libc6) => /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so.12
        libmysqlclient.so.10 (libc6) => /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so.10
        libmysqlclient.so (libc6) => /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so
```

This tells you that there's a very good chance that MySQL is installed. Its very rare that someone would install the shared objects only, without installing at least the client. Now, check for the existence of the actual client and server:

```
root@tower:~ # which mysqld_safe
/usr/bin/mysqld_safe
root@tower:~ # which mysql
/usr/bin/mysql
root@tower:~ #
```

The `which' program may not be installed, so check for it via:

```
root@tower:~ # which which
/usr/bin/which
```

Hope this helps. Short of querying the package manager (kind of hard to do in a script if you have many systems running different distributions) it seems a very reliable way to tell.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest and most distro-agnostic way of answering your question is;

```
find / -name mysql
```